# Unexpected token import in vuejs router with laravel mix and eslint

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, eslint, laravel-mix

I have a laravel project that uses VueJS and Vue-Router to manage the front-end. I just installed eslint and configured it with some default presets, but as soon as I add the mix.webpackConfig block to the webpack.mix.js folder, it suddenly errors out on the ES2015 import() function I'm using to asynchronously load vue components.

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.webpackConfig({
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  }
})

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
  .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

As soon as I remove the mix.webpackConfig() block it works fine. I don't understand why adding eslint-loader in there would suddenly break babel.

Here is the specific file I'm using the import() function on. Someone else had a similar problem but they discovered a typo in the filename, and I've triple-checked that.

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import App from './views/App.vue'
import Home from './views/Home.vue'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,

  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      meta: { layout: 'no-sidebar-no-container' },
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'login',
      meta: { layout: 'no-sidebar' },
      component: () => import('./views/Login.vue')
    },
    {
      path: '/admin',
      name: 'admin',
      meta: { layout: 'no-sidebar' },
      component: () => import('./views/Admin.vue')
    },
    {
      path: '/events',
      name: 'events',
      meta: { layout: 'no-sidebar' },
      component: () => import('./views/Events.vue')
    },
    {
      path: '/course/:courseId',
      name: 'course',
      component: () => import('./views/Course.vue')
    },
    {
      path: '/edit/course/:courseId',
      name: 'edit-course',
      meta: { layout: 'no-sidebar' },
      component: () => import('./views/Admin/EditCourse.vue')
    },
    {
      path: '/edit/course/newcourse',
      name: 'edit-newcourse',
      meta: { layout: 'no-sidebar' },
      component: () => import('./views/Admin/EditCourse.vue')
    },
    {
      path: '/edit/eventspage',
      name: 'edit-eventspage',
      meta: { layout: 'no-sidebar' },
      component: () => import('./views/Admin/EditEventsPage.vue')
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: did you create `.babelrc` file?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I didn't figure it out, but I fixed it by using 'laravel-mix-eslint' instead, as described here:

https://laravel-mix.com/extensions/eslint

Now instead of that block, I have this:

```js
require('laravel-mix-eslint');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
  .eslint()
  .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```